# Haskell: Do we have short cut for mapCons

Tags: haskell

I mean write such a function：

```
mapCons x [] = [[x]]
mapCons x ys = map (x:) ys
```

so that:

```
*> mapCons 'a' []
["a"]
*> mapCons 'a' ["cat", "dog"]
["acat","adog"]
```

Do we have short-cut or pre-defined functions for mapCons?
I tried Hoogle a->[[a]]->[[a]], but didn't find ideal one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm curious: what's your use case for this?

Comment: PLease notice: An empty list (`[]`) is different from a list of an empty list (`[[]]`). Your first case does not makes any sense.

Comment: There are many questions about the [] case. It happens typically in DFS(deep-first-search). For example, selecting elements from a list so that the sum of them meet some criteria. When you find x as a candidate, you next recursively go on search among the rest, and the result is xss, you need cons x with every xs in xss, however, if the recursive search failed, you get[], (not [[]]). It doesn't mean the whole search failed, [[x]] will be the answer.

Comment: @Larry if you meant the function equivalent to `\n -> filter ((==n) . sum) . subsequences`, then I don't see how `[[x]]` is useful. The function I imagine is `search 0 l = [[]]; search n [] = []; search n (h:t) = search n t ++ map (h:) (search (n-h) t)`, no use for `[[x]]`.

Answer (score 11):

No, and I note that `map (x:)` is 8 characters long while typing `mapCons x` is 9 characters.  For such specific operations (i.e. non-generic operations) the cost and difficulty of finding or remembering them far out weighs the benefits of having them.  Imagine if the prelude or base libraries defined 100,000 functions - shudder!

Comment: Note that the OP's `mapCons` gives a different result when given `[]` --- which reinforces your point about very specialised functions not being in the standard libraries.

Comment: @Thomas +1, some hilarious observation:)

Answer (score 2):

If you `import Control.Applicative` you can do things like this:

```
GOA Control.Applicative> (:) 'a' <$> ["cat", "dog"]
["acat","adog"]
GOA Control.Applicative> (:) <$> [0] <*> [[1,2,3], [7,8,9]]
[[0,1,2,3],[0,7,8,9]]
GOA Control.Applicative> liftA2 (:) "a" ["cat", "dog"]
["acat","adog"]
```

I know this doesn't satisfy the `a->[[a]]->[[a]]` signature you posted, but your question is a bit unclear as to what you are trying to do so I thought this still might help.

Comment: It should be just `(:) 'a' <$> ["cat", "dog"]`, right? Why complicate things with an additional list?

Comment: It should be, yes. Some things are better not done in the morning ;-) Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Hi, I think this is just sugar for map . (:), It doesn't satisfied the [] case. One option is to use [[]] but not [] to indicate a failed search (see my comments previously about DFS problem). I post this question just for curious about if there exist some `one-line' solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily replace mapCons by a simple list comprehension:

```
mapCons x ys = [x:y | y<-ys]
```

Like the other solutions, it returns `[]` if fed with empty `ys`, not `[[x]]` as your definition.

Comment: Hi, Beside the [] case, this solution lost the ability to handle infinity list ys.

Comment: @Larry, no, it handles infinite lists well enough.

Comment: Sorry, my fault: take 5 $ mapCons 'a' (cycle ["cat", "dog"]) ==> ["acat","adog","acat","adog","acat"]

Answer (score 1):

If we disregard the empty-list case, which, as FUZxxl noticed, does not make much sense, you may notice that:

```
mapCons = map . (:)
```

Which, when read out loud, yields something tautological like "mapCons is equal to map composed with cons".

Does not seem useful to me.

Comment: Another use case example is looking up all candidate words with a given prefix (as far as user typed) in a Trie-like dictionary. When the looking up program arrives at the last letter x, and it is the leaf node. We just have [[x]] as the singleton list. If it is a branch node, we recursively looking up the children, so there will be multiple candidate words. However, if x is a typo, there is no word with the given prefix in the dictionary. Return [[]] means there is ONE candidate and it is empty []. While [] means there is no candidate at all.

Comment: Hmm, and why would you want to return an empty candidate when the user has made a typo and there is no candidate at all?

Comment: for example:
case 1, user input: "a", result: ["a", "an", "and", "another"];
case 2, user input: "an", result: ["an", "and", "another"];
case 3, user input: "anz", result: []

Another option for case 3 is ["an"] to indicate the typo.